# Why my custom route does not pass the right path to the child component?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have these routes inside my App.js file:

```
<LoggedInRoute userData={userData} path="/code/:id/view">
  <ViewCode />
</LoggedInRoute>
<LoggedInRoute userData={userData} path="/code/feed/:userId">
  <CodeFeed />
</LoggedInRoute>
// userData -> state representing user session info
```

Here it is my LoggedInRoute component:

```
import React from 'react';

import { Redirect, Route } from "react-router-dom";

function LoggedInRoute(props) {
  return (
    <Route
      render={({ location }) =>
        props.userData.id ? (
          props.children
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: "/login",
              state: { from: location }
            }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  );
}

export default LoggedInRoute;
```

I am using the useParams() function (from react-router-dom) to extra id and userId in my child components ViewCode and CodeFeed. now the problem is that are extracted as undefined values. If I use Route instead of LoggedInRoute, everything works fine. It seems like my LoggedInRoute component doesn't pass the path to the child components. I checked the location object, from useLocation(), and the path it's the right one in the child components. What I am missing? Thanks in advance, guys :)

Answer (score 0):

This solved my issue:

```
import React from 'react';

import { Redirect, Route } from "react-router-dom";

function LoggedInRoute(props) {
  return (
    <Route
      path={props.path}
      render={({ location }) =>
        props.userData.id ? (
          props.children
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: "/login",
              state: { from: location }
            }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  );
}

export default LoggedInRoute;
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you are not passing through any routing props to the `Route` component you are rendering. No `path` prop means it can't match URL paths.

```
function LoggedInRoute(props) {
  return (
    <Route
      // <-- missing is any path or any other route prop
      render={({ location }) =>
        props.userData.id ? (
          props.children
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: "/login",
              state: { from: location }
            }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  );
}
```

To resolve you can destructure the custom props and spread the rest into the `Route` component.

```
function LoggedInRoute({ children, userData, ...props }) {
  return (
    <Route
      {...props} // path and other non-destructered props spread in
      render={({ location }) =>
        userData.id ? (
          children
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: "/login",
              state: { from: location }
            }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  );
}
```

But this code could be improved. Instead of rendering a `Route` and trying to do all the logic in the `render` prop function, move the logic into the `LoggedInRoute` component body and conditionally render a `Route` with ***all*** the route props passed through, or the redirect.

```
function LoggedInRoute({ userData, ...props }) {
  const location = useLocation();

  return userData?.id ? (
    <Route {...props} />
  ) : (
    <Redirect
      to={{
        pathname: "/login",
        state: { from: location }
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should spread the props to the Route component that you wrap with your custom one.

```
import { Redirect, Route } from "react-router-dom";

function LoggedInRoute(props) {
  return (
    <Route
      ...props
      render={({ location }) =>
        props.userData.id ? (
          props.children
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: "/login",
              state: { from: location }
            }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  );
}

export default LoggedInRoute;
```